# Laravel - How to catch a database exception? Code 500

Tags: php, exception, laravel

i created a register form with laravel. The email column in the database is classified as UNIQUE. If  i registered one user with a email address and want to send the form a second time I want to catch this exception and show an error message to the user.

But currently the only thing that i can identify is that a code 500 gets back to me and i have no chance to catch that exception to display a more user friendly message.

My code is as follows and my question is how can i detect that `$user->save` has not happened and the app should not fire back a code 500.

```
 //Storing the data to the database 
    try {
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = Input::get('name');
    $user->surname = Input::get('sname');
        $user->email = Input::get('email');
        $user->activatehash = str_random(25);
        $user->ip = Request::getClientIp();
        $status = $user->save();
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        //Do something when query fails. 
        return View::make("register", array('error' => 'true'))->withInput(Input::all());
    }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you messed with Validator class? http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Yeah I'd say you should probably check priror to an insertion if the e-mail address has been taken or not.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [Ardent](https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent). Then you can define a rule to make sure your email is unique prior to saving:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'email' => array('required', 'unique', 'email')
);
```